# Array map function

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I use Array map function to replace one of the updated objects?

I have Array of an object.
The object property can be updated by the user. When the operation is successful The local cache needs to be updated.

```
private _setUpdatedReportingEntity( collection:Array<any>, item:ReportingEntity): any
{
    let updatedCollection = collection.map( function(v){
        if( v.otherCompanyId === item.otherCompanyId){

            return item;
        }else{
            return v;
        }

    });
    return updatedCollection;
}
```

Will this function replace the old object with new Object?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will replace the old object with new object in updated array created with `map` method without mutating original array.

You can leverage ES6 and make code shorter.

```
collection.map(v => (v.otherCompanyId === item.otherCompanyId ? item : v));
```